# Is there a MemoryLeak?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, datagrid

I load a List of LiefItems.

```
List<LiefItem> list = this.LoadLiefItems();
```

LiefItem is implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on this way:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

After loading the List, I am subscribing to PropertyChanged:

```
foreach(var item in list) {
    item.PropertyChanged += ItemOnPropertyChanged;
}
```

After, the List will be used as a ItemsSource of a DataGrid.

I asking me now, if load the list a second time and set the new List as ItemsSource of my DataGrid, are the first loaded items removed from the Memory or does I have a MemoryLeak because I am subscribing to PropertyChanged and don't unsubscribe?

Comment: I think you should be fine. With the event subscribing, your items have a reference to the DataGrid; your DataGrid doesn't have a reference to them. So long as you properly clear/replace your `List<LiefItem> list` collection so nothing is referencing it or its elements, I think they'll be collected eventually.

Comment: As long as you dont hold a static reference to the list, and there is no static event, you should be ok.

Comment: The only real risk here is that, depending on your design, you may continue to receive property change notifications from items in the old list if there's any code hanging onto them and modifying them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No memory leak there.

C# events implement [subject-observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern underneath.

When an event is raised, what actually happens underneath is a call to the member method of the object that was registered to the event.

So, if you do something like:

```
 item.PropertyChanged += ItemOnPropertyChanged;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
 item.PropertyChanged += this.ItemOnPropertyChanged;
```

And when the event is triggered, there's an invocation of that method:

```
registeredObject.ItemOnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
```

This means that a reference is stored for the object which registered for the event. Not the object that raises the event.